# regarding a extensioncontroller

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension

How can we define Function declaration in the apex as I am getting this error Invalid type: function

```
public class DownloadController {

    public DownloadController(ApexPages.StandardController Download){

    } 

    function downloadTest(string selectedValue){

    }
}
```

Comment: this is not the best place to ask this kind of question, please take some time to read [ask] and take the [tour] in order to get familiar with the forum. You might want to get familair with [Trailheads](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_database) in order to learn apex. thanks, and welcome to SFSE!

Comment: You can't define a "function declaration" in Apex

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to read [Class Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_defining_methods.htm). Here's the appropriate signature form, directly from the documentation:

> [public | private | protected | global] [override] [static]
> ***data_type*** method_name  (input parameters)  {
>
> // The body of the method
>
> }

Where anything within `[]` are optional (depending on the needs of the method), and `|` indicates that you may choose one of the options within the `[]`.

For the possible values of ***data_type***, you'll want to read more about [Data Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_data_types.htm). I will not include all of the possible values here, so you'll need to do some reading, but typical types include `void` (the non-value type), `String` for normal text, `Boolean` for true/false values, `Integer` or `Decimal` for numbers, and `Date` and `DateTime` for temporal values.

In addition, methods may also include [annotations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation.htm):

> To add an annotation to a method, specify it immediately before the method or class definition. For example:
>
> ```
> global class MyClass {
>      @future
>      Public static void myMethod(String a)
>      {
>           //long-running Apex code
>      }
> }
> ```